# Blender Three.js export tool giving bizarre results

Tags: javascript, three.js

I've been for a time trying to export animations to Three.js, but it only produces bizarre results. Code:

```
var jsonLoader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
jsonLoader.load("walkcycle/walkingCycle.js",function(geometry,materials){
    chr = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials));
    /*THREE.AnimationHandler.add(geometry.animations[1]);*/
    /*for (var i=0,l=materials.length; i<l; ++i)*/
        /*materials[0].skinning = true;*/
    /*animation = new THREE.Animation( chr, "Walking" );*/
    /*animation.play(0.05);*/
    /*chr.scale.set(5,5,5);*/
    scene.add(chr);
});
```

Original mesh on Blender:

[mesh http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/62862049/Screenshots/01n.png](http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/62862049/Screenshots/01n.png)

Result on Three.js:

[result http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/62862049/Screenshots/01o.png](http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/62862049/Screenshots/01o.png)

I'm using Blender 2.7 and the latest exporter on Three.js's master branch. What could be going on?

Comment: That output looks correct to me! ;) Could you share the .blend file?

Comment: Hello mrdoob, sure. I'm having problems with my server so I [uploaded it in a random host](http://www.datafilehost.com/d/33d43d3d), let me know if it doesn't work. Would you be kind enough to tell me what I am doing wrong in the (commented) animation part, too? With some other files I was able to export the mesh, but `geometry.animation` was undefined. I used `geometry.animations[1]` instead, but it showed a lot of webgl (too many uniforms) when I tried uncommenting the `materials[0].skinning = true` line.

Comment: Actually. Considering that you have a .blend file to test. Do you mind opening a issue on github as a bug report? https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/new